# Slow rising edge in timing diagram with tikztimingtable

Tags: tikz-timing

I want to draw a slow rising edge with the `tikztimingtable` to show metastable behavior of a Flip-Flop.

I tried using `[timing/slope=1.0]` but the width of the rising edge width was too narrow.

```
\begin{tikztimingtable}
C1                      & 3L l  5{5C} H                 \\
C2                      & 4L    5{5C} h                 \\
A                       & 2L [timing/slope=1.0] 24H h   \\
B1                      & 3L l m MMMMM 4L l 16H         \\
B2                      & 4L     MMMMM 20H h            \\
\end{tikztimingtable}
```

[image: too narrow rising edge]

Following is what brings me closest to what I want.

The problem is I can't get rid of that little spike in Signal A.

```
\begin{tikztimingtable}
C1                      & 3L l  5{5C} H                  \\
C2                      & 4L    5{5C} h                  \\
A                       & 2L !{-- +(3,1)--++(3,0)} 24H h \\
B1                      & 3L l m MMMMM 4L l 16H          \\
B2                      & 4L     MMMMM 20H h             \\
\end{tikztimingtable}
```

[image: Resulting Picture]

When I leave the y-value of the second point for the line on 1, like this `!{-- +(3,1)--++(3,1)}`, the following High-levels are set a line height above. (Can't post a picture of it since I am only allowed to post 2 links...)

- Is it possible to set the reference point at the right position, so that I can continue using H, L, M, etc.?
- Another solution could be drawing the whole timing for Signal A. Is that the best way?

Comment: tikz-timing manual. Pg. 48 is the example where i got the idea of using `!{-- +(.5,.5) -- ++(1,0)}`.
http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-timing/tikz-timing.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same challenge when trying to draw mixed-signal waveforms. It took me a while to familiarize myself with the multiple layers of languages (tikz, pgf, etc.). I think you are very close to the answer.

I cannot test the code right now, but I think you just need to use "--++" instead of "-- +"

```tex
\begin{tikztimingtable}
C1                      & 3L l  5{5C} H                  \\
C2                      & 4L    5{5C} h                  \\
A                       & 2L !{--++(3,1)--++(3,0)} 24H h \\
B1                      & 3L l m MMMMM 4L l 16H          \\
B2                      & 4L     MMMMM 20H h             \\
\end{tikztimingtable}
```

I created this standalone tex source that demonstrates all the tricks I learned. If my answer above is incorrect, you should be able to discover by comparing my examples.

```tex
%\documentclass{article}  % Needed if you want to add subsections and more complicated documentation
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}

\usetikztiminglibrary{overlays}

\begin{document}
%
\def\junkSEQ{LLHHLLHL}
\def\Dfoobar{2z3D{Foo};[black]3D{Bar}2z}

\def\waveX1{2}
\def\mySin{!{[x=2ex,y=1ex,thick] ++(0,0) sin(\waveX1-1,1) cos(\waveX1,0)  sin(\waveX1+1,-1) cos(\waveX1+2,0)}}
\def\myCos{!{[x=2ex,y=1ex,thick] ++(0,1) cos(1,0) sin(2,-1) cos(3,0)  sin(4,1)}}
%

\begin{tikztimingtable}
  [timing/d/background/.style={fill=white},timing/lslope=0,]
    {let tikz\_timing connect anchors "naturally"} &
        LL[gray] ;[green] \junkSEQ ;[red] \junkSEQ ; \\
        \\
    {move pen location} &  
        [gray]   LL; 
        [pink]   !{(1,1)};
        [green]  \junkSEQ ;
        [blue]   !{(3,-2)};    
        [red]    \junkSEQ ; \\
        \\
        \\
    {Draw line with "- -"; Origin=(0,0)} & 
        [blue]  !{(0,0) --(5,0) --(3,1)   --(2,-1)   --(5,2)};
        \\
        \\
    {Draw line and move pen once "- - +"; Origin=(5,0)} & 
        [blue]  !{(0,0) --(5,0) --+(3,1)  --+(2,-1)  --+(5,2)};
        \\ 
        \\
    {\textcolor{red}{!!USE THIS<<} Draw line and keep moving pen "- - + +"; Origin=Tracking } & 
        [blue]  !{(0,0) --(5,0) --++(3,1) --++(2,-1) --++(5,2)};
        \\
        \\
        \\        
    {'Analog' Drawing: Everything referenced to (0,0); data loss "- -"} &  
        [gray]   LL; 
        [green]  !{--(1,0)};    
        [orange] !{--(1,1)};     
        [blue]   !{--(1,0)};
        [yellow] !{--(1,-1)};   
        [pink]   !{--(1,2)};
        [green]  LLHHLLH;
        [blue]   !{--(1,-2)};    
        [red]    LLHHLLH; \\
        \\ 
        \\
        \\
    {'Analog' Drawing: Additional lines anchor to last stopping point; "- - + +" \textcolor{red}{!!USE THIS<<}} &  
        [gray]   LL; 
        [green]  !{--++(1,0)};    
        [orange] !{--++(1,1)};     
        [blue]   !{--++(1,0)};
        [yellow] !{--++(1,-1)};   
        [pink]   !{--++(1,2)};
        [green]  LLHHLLH;
        [blue]   !{--++(1,-2)};     
        [red]    HLLHHLLH; \\
        \\  
    {Node Marking} &  
        [blue]  LL; 
        [blue]  N(A)LLHH3{L};
        [blue]  HLN(A1)HHHLN(A2)HLN(A3)H;    
        [blue]  LLHHLLH; \\
        \\    
    {Node Marking (Continued)} &  
        [blue]  LL; 
        [blue]  5HN(B);    
        [blue]  4LN(B0)H2N(B1)LHN(B2)2L; \\
        \\  
    {sin + TODO variables} &
        !{[x=1.57ex,y=1ex] [pink,thick](0,0) sin (1,1) cos (2,0)  sin (3,-1) cos (4,0)}; 
        !{[x=1.57ex,y=1ex] [yellow,thick](0,1) cos (1,0) sin (2,-1) cos (3,0)  sin (4,1)}; 
        [brown,rounded corners,thick] LLHHLH;
        !{++(-6,-1.6)};  [red,rounded corners,thick] HLHHLH;
        !{[x=1.57ex,y=1ex,thick] [purple](10,0) sin (11,1) cos (12,0)  sin (13,-1) cos (14,0)}; 
        !{[x=1.57ex,y=1*2.5ex,thick] [orange](10,1) cos (11,0) sin (12,-1) cos (13,0)  sin (14,1)};
        \\
        \\
    {offset +  split decision + overlay} &  
        [gray]  LL; 
        [blue]  !{--+(0,-.5)};    
        [green] LLHHLLZ ; 
        [red]   O{LLU}{[dotted] HH;}
        [orange] O{UU}{MM}; 
        [gray,timing/lslope=0.2]  HLHL;
        [blue,timing/lslope=1]  O{LLH}{[dotted] HHH;} 
        [timing/lslope=1] O{[orange] HLL}{[green,dotted] LLL};
        \\
        \\
    {Sequence - Copy + Paste code(2z3D\{Foo\}3D\{Bar\}2z MM 2z3D\{Foo\}3D\{Bar\}2z)} & 
        [orange] 2z3D{Foo}3D{Bar}2z MM 2z3D{Foo}3D{Bar}2z; \\
    {Sequence - use "def" for reuse code(Dfoobar MM Dfoobar)} & 
        [red]  \Dfoobar MM [green] \Dfoobar; \\
        \\
% #TODO#
    {sin + define} &
        !{(0,0)}; [pink]\mySin;
%        !{(4,1)}; [red]\myCos;
%        !{(16,1)}; [blue]\mySin; 
%        !{(10,1)}; [green]\myCos;
        \\
        \\        
    {scan test} & !{[domain=0:8,scale=0.5]plot (\x,{sin(\x r*10)})} \\
  \begin{extracode}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \begin{scope}[semitransparent]
        \vertlines[gray]{0,1,2,...,25}
      \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{background}[line width=0.35pt]
      \draw [black,semithick,double] (A.mid) ellipse (.2 and .6) (B.mid) ellipse (.2 and .6);
      \draw [black] [decoration,decoration=zigzag,double] ($(A.mid)-(0,.6)$) parabola[bend pos=0.5] ($(B.mid)+(0,.6)$);
    \end{background}
    \begin{background}[timing/picture,thick,color=red,dotted]
        \foreach \ia/\ib in {1/0,2/1,3/2} {
          \draw [red, semithick ,-, dotted]  ($(A\ia.mid)+(0,-.5)$)  parabola[bend pos=0.95]($(B\ib.mid)$);
          \draw (A\ia.mid) ellipse(.2 and .6) (B\ib.mid) ellipse(.2 and .6);
        }
      \end{background}
  \end{extracode}
\end{tikztimingtable}
%
%
\end{document}
```

I think your solution will be similar to this example of mine (look at the green-blue-red section of the 7th trace down):

```tex
{'Analog' Drawing: Additional lines anchor to last stopping point; "- - + +" \textcolor{red}{!!USE THIS<<}} &  
    [gray]   LL; 
    [green]  !{--++(1,0)};    
    [orange] !{--++(1,1)};     
    [blue]   !{--++(1,0)};
    [yellow] !{--++(1,-1)};   
    [pink]   !{--++(1,2)};
    [green]  LLHHLLH;
    [blue]   !{--++(1,-2)};     
    [red]    HLLHHLLH;
```

The output of the tex is below:
[image]

I hope it saves you the many hours it took me to figure out!

Comment: Thank you! Great Reference Card and solved my problem :) Should be in the manual!

Comment: For the "reference card" there's now VisualTikZ, check it out